# Função em Racket - Comparação de caracteres a partir de uma string

Tags: programação-funcional

Boa noite, estou começando agora a aprender Racket para a faculdade e estou com uma função implementada que não entendo a razão de não estar dando certo. O objetivo é receber uma string e um caracter e retornar quantas vezes o caracter aparece na string. ex: Em "banana" o caracter "#\a" aparece 3 vezes, logo a função deveria retornar 3.
Porém apenas tenho 0 como resposta.

```
(define (numCaracter c s1 numC x)
   (cond
     [(equal? x (string-length s1)) numC]
     [(equal? c (string-ref s1 x)) (numCaracter c s1 (add1 numC) (add1 x))]
     [else (numCaracter c s1 numC (add1 x))]))
```

Inclusive se vale citar estou testando a função da seguinte forma (numCaracter "#\a" "banana" 0 0). Desde já agradeço a atenção.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O erro está em passar "#\a" em vez de #\a na avaliação:

```
(numCaracter "#\a" "banana" 0 0)
```

No entanto sugiro que faças com uma função auxiliar e assim apenas envias o caracter e o string na avaliação, assim:

```
(define (numCaracter character string1)
  (numCaracter-aux character string1 0 0))

    (define (numCaracter-aux c s1 numC x)
       (cond
         ((= x (string-length s1)) numC)
         ((equal? c (string-ref s1 x)) (numCaracter-aux c s1 (+ 1 numC) (+ 1 x)))
         (else (numCaracter-aux c s1 numC (+ 1 x))))) 

    (numCaracter #\a "banana")
```

Espero ter ajudado.